# I am not able to add support library to my Android Studio Project

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am trying to open someone else's project in my Android studio. I installed all the missing libraries and yet I am facing an issue with the appcompat theme.

Here is the screenshot of my styles.xml:
[image: Styles.xml]

And here is the screenshot of my build.gradle file:
[image]

I cannot see the preview of any layout nor I am able to run the project because of this dependency issue. I am not able to figure out why the dependency is not being added to the project.

**Adding Dependencies Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: check your sdk manager

Comment: I have the support library installed. Do I need to check anything else?

Comment: whats your gradle version

Comment: what is your ? `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:`

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta1'

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thanks a lot!! It was the buggy beta version that was causing the issue. Working like a charm now

Comment: Check your target sdk make it 25,your compile SDk version is 25 may be it help

Comment: @SunilChaudhary yes

Comment: Anyone arriving here because they failed adding 'compile' statement to build.gradle note that there are TWO build.gradle files, and compile must be added to the dependencies section of the file that has no dependencies section (the one with targetSdkVersion = x etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### FYI

Alpha,Beta version is not stable .You should use stable version instead of that

**These version of a piece of software that is made available for testing,**

**Use**

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'//2.2.3
```

You should use same type of version

```
 compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
 targetSdkVersion 25
```

Comment: Thanks!! Worked like a charm!!

Comment: @BhargavMehta Move ahead .